# Java Selenium ElementNotInteractableException not thrown

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I am pretty new with java with selenium and got another question regarding the exception handling in selenium (or generally in java):

I got a method which should return an web element. If the element is not found then the NotFound Exception should be thrown:

```
public WebElement getElementByXpath(String xpath, WebDriver driver) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Test1");
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e2) {
        System.out.println("Element " + xpath + " not found");
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is already working fine.
But now I want to add another exception:

```
public WebElement getElementByXpath(String xpath, WebDriver driver) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Test1");
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException e1) {
        System.out.println("Element " + xpath + " not interactable");
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e2) {
        System.out.println("Element " + xpath + " not found");
    }

    return null;
}
```

But if the ElementNotInteractableException got thrown I got the regular error message and not my exception:

```
 Test1
2022-03-08 08:08:11.314 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.80)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
.
.
.
```

Did I understand the exception handling in java wrong?
I only want that the app returns "Element " + xpath + " not interactable".
I thought I could add several exceptions which could be handled. Or did I something wrong?

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: `findElement` won't throw `ElementNotInteractableException`, if you get this exception it's not from this code.

Comment: @Guy: Thank you for the Info. The Exception works fine when I put it in the code block where I call the Method "getElementByXpath". Thank you for your help!